# Visual Studio 2015 will not target Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

My installation of Visual Studio 2015 will not target any Windows 10 SDK version despite having the Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.10586 (and Update 2) installed.

When I open a solution that has Windows 10 as a target and attempt to build it, I get told I don't have that SDK version installed.

[image: Build error]

Checking the target platform version, I can see that there is no option to selection any 10.* versions.

[image: Visual Studio options]

However looking at the VS install, I can see that the Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.10586 is marked as installed.

[image: VS install options]

Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.10586 should let me target it as well as 10.0.10240, but I am unable to target/build against either.

I've tried:

- uninstalling and reinstalling VS2015 with both SDKs selected (time-consuming but no change),
- repairing the VS2015 install (time-consuming but no change),
- uninstalling 10.0.10586 and installing 10.0.10240 separately and simultaneously (always an installation error 15605 on 10.0.10240),
- installing standalone versions of the SDK (always an error that 10.0.10586 is installed).

Comment: What are the values in your project csproj of TargetPlatformVersion and SDKReference?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I went to Control panel and uninstalled 10.0.10586, then went to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive and downloaded 10.0.10586 SDK and installed it again.  After this, it worked.